# Django 1.9 cannot pass context variable to template using {{}}

Tags: python, django

I don't know why I cannot use context to pass my template, I checked online, I have to use context processor and also set context processor in my `settings.py`, why can I not use this to pass the context from `view.py` to template. I use django 1.9

In `view.py`:

```
  from .models import Product
  def sellmainpage(request):
      products=Product.objects.all()
      context={
           'products'= products
      return render(request,'sell.html',context)
```

In `sell.html`:

```
  {% for product in products}
     <span>{{product.name}}</span>
  {% endfor %}
```

Comment: Is that your code? If so that's not even correct python syntax. It should be `context={'products': products}`.

Comment: Don't know if it's a typo in pasting, but you are missing `'%'`: `{% for product in products %}`

Comment: sorry, those syntax error is typo, after my code don't have the syntax error. but I still cannot pass the context to template

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your model is

```
class Product(models.Model):
    product=models.CharField(max_length=200)
    companyname=models.ForeignKey(Company)
    description=models.TextField() 
    price=models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2,max_digits=10) 
    stock=models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

Then you **don't have a field called `name`**, maybe you want the field `product` or `companyname`?

```
  {% for product in products %}
     <span>{{product.product}}</span>
  {% endfor %}
```

or

```
  {% for product in products %}
     <span>{{product.companyname}}</span>
  {% endfor %}
```

If that still doesn't work you want to check `len(products)` to see if it's not empty.

<sub>*I would like to kindly point out that you have lots of "trivial" syntax issues, I strongly recommend you read the errors thrown back to you by Django and Python, and learn how to debug off those. Also I'd follow a tutorial to iron out my skills.*</sub>

In Python you form a dictionary like this

```
context={'products': products}
```

Not

```
context={'products'= products} # Wrong syntax, don't use
```

If you insist on using the `=` sign, you can use `dict`

```
context = dict(products=products)
```

And thanks to @DeepSpace comment, you also have this problem, a missing closing `%}`

```
{% for product in products %}
                           ^
                           |__ You missed this %
```

Comment: OP is also missing a  '%': `{% for product in products %}`. Perhaps you want to add that to your answer.

Comment: sorry, those syntax error is typo, after my code don't have the syntax error. but I still cannot pass the context to template

Comment: @BoCao Assuming `Product` model has a field `name`, the code looks fine to me, what error do you get? Also make sure your `products` queryset is not empty, can `print len(products)`

Comment: @bakkal , yes ,i have Product class in my models. my template cannot show the product's name in my product

Comment: @bakkal, I follow your change, but it is still not working. I have trey to use context_processor in setting and create a context_processor.py, It works. But I don't know why I cannot use this simple way to do it